# MySQL: index on JSON array

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table with the next data:

```
|ID.   | COUNTRY_CODES             |
|------|--------------------------|
|657041|"[""US"", ""DE""]"        |
|657045|"[""US"", ""GB"", ""IN""]"|
|657046|"[""US""]"                |
|657050|"[""US"", ""DE""]"        |
```

and next query:

```
SELECT id, country_code FROM offers WHERE "US" MEMBER OF(country_codes)
```

However, I have added the next index:

```
KEY country_codes ((cast(country_codes as char(2) array)))
```

Table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `offers` (
`id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`country_codes_by_target_groups` text DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `country_codes2` ((cast(`country_codes_by_target_groups` as char(2) array))),
KEY `country_codes3` ((cast(json_extract(`country_codes_by_target_groups`,_utf8mb4'$.arr') as char(2) array)))
```

) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=657081 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

The output of the explain (it's for development BD but for real data I have the same):

```
1   SIMPLE  offers      ALL                 155 100.00  Using where
```

MySQL doesn't use it.
I cannot understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Run `SELECT VERSION();` and tell us what it reports. You need at least MySQL 8.0.17 to use the multi-valued index feature. Older versions of MySQL don't support that syntax.

Comment: Your index looks fine and could be used. Maybe there is a better one? Can you provide the actual execution plan (add `explain ` infront of your query) and potentially the table description (the output of `show create table offers` (you can remove all columns that are not relevant, but include all indexes mentioned in the explain output).

Comment: @BillKarwin no, the version of Mysql is 8.0.23

Comment: Another idea: MySQL typically doesn't use an index if it senses that the value you are searching for is very common in your table. There's no advantage to the index if a table-scan would get the same result in a less expensive way.

Comment: I suspect the problem maybe in the type of the column - `text` probably it should be `json`

Comment: Okay I just tested it in my own Docker container with MySQL 8.0.26. I get `type: ref` in the EXPLAIN, searching for the value 'US'.

Comment: Strange but for me it doesn't work, even doesn't use it as a possible key.

Comment: Looks like AWS RDS doesn't use multi-valued Indexes even for Mysql 8.0.26